# R and Predictions

Tags: r

If I use *linear model*, *generalized linear model*, *partial least squares* etc packages in R, and train it where, given key response variable `RSP`, the formula argument is of the form:

```
formula <- as.formula("f(RSP)~A + B + C") # use A,B,C predictors only
```

or

```
formula <- as.formula("f(RSP)~.") # use ALL predictors
```

and `f(RSP)` is some transformation function, such that:

```
f <- function(x){...}
```

when I then predict after training, would the returned prediction set need to have the anti-function applied? If `P <- predict(...)` is `P` of the form `RSP` or `f(RSP)`, such that the true prediction: `Pt`, - needs to have the antifunction `g(P)` applied?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for general `f` then I guess you'll want to write yourself a `family` object and hand that to `glm`.

There are examples in the help page for `family`. See in particular the parameterised `logexp` function, which makes a fancy parameterised link function which is added to a more traditional distribution assumption and then handed to `glm`. I'm guessing that's your case. This will, as you suspect, require both `f` and its inverse function, plus some other stuff.

Once that's in place, `predict(model, newdata=blah, type='response')` *should* (although I admit I have not checked) give you the expected response, and you'll get the linear predictor by leaving out `type`, as is R's odd default behaviour.

I'm a bit unclear on the potential statistical consequences of doing this, i.e. the effect on Deviance computations etc. so perhaps others will dive in.  But that seems to be the 'computational' answer.